# Mathematica plot, exclude endpoints?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Why does the following give me errors about dividing by 0?

```
ParametricPlot[{1/Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 3 Pi}, Exclusions -> Sin[t] == 0]
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
```

It does successfully exclude the points at Pi and 2 Pi, but not the points at 0 and 3 Pi.  If I exclude the endpoints by changing the interval...

```
ParametricPlot[{1/Sin[t], t}, {t, 0.001, 2.999 Pi}, Exclusions -> Sin[t] == 0]
```

I get no errors.

How do you exclude the endpoints of a plot?

thanks,
Rob

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? In 7.0 the endpoints are excluded without fudging the interval, but the errors are still emitted.

Comment: I'm using 7.0 (student edition, OS X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you can reformulate the plot with `Csc[t]` instead of `1/Sin[t]` and things seem to work:

```
ParametricPlot[{Csc[t], t}, {t, 0, 3 Pi}, Exclusions -> {Sin[t] == 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I suspect the behavior with `1/Sin[t]` is simply a bug and will report it as such.

As a more-general workaround, you can wrap your original expression with `Quiet` to surpress the error messages:

```
Quiet[ParametricPlot[{1/Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 3 Pi}, 
    Exclusions -> Sin[t] == 0], Power::infy]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about Quiet.